# solr count items with certain fields

Tags: solr, lucene

I have an index in solr which has say the following fields:

```
name
address
mobile
email
```

all fields are of type `text_general`. the problem is, in some items, some fields are missing and I want to count these. So, for example, here is an item on the index with only the following two fields:

```
name
address
```

So, for example, I would like to count the total number of items with field `name` populated (ie name is exists in that item).

I think it sounds trivial but reading the docs I am unsure how to formulate such a query.

I have tried this, thanks to @MatsLindh - here I am searching for all items with field `full_name` which all of them have got:

```
>>> requests.get('http://localhost:8984/solr/solr_search_service/select', params={
... 'facet': 'true',
... 'facet.query': 'full_name:[* TO *]',
... 'wt': 'json',
... 'rows': 2,
... 'start': 0,
... }).json()
{'responseHeader': {'status': 0, 'QTime': 10, 'params': {'facet.query': 'full_name:[* TO *]', 'start': '0', 'rows': '2', 'facet': 'true', 'wt': 'json'}}, 'response': {'numFound': 0, 'start': 0, 'numFoundExact': True, 'docs': []}, 'facet_counts': {'facet_queries': {'full_name:[* TO *]': 0}, 'facet_fields': {}, 'facet_ranges': {}, 'facet_intervals': {}, 'facet_heatmaps': {}}}
```

but somehow gives me zero as the count :(

Comment: `name:[* TO *]` will give you all documents with a value in `name`. You can use a faceting query to generate counts for how many documents match these queries, like `&facet=true&facet.query=name:[* TO *]&facet.query=address:[* TO *]` - those two facets will then have counts for how many documents have values in those two fields. Is that what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @MatsLindh I have updated the post.. something seems wrong because I see to get zero as the answer.. hmm

Comment: You need to have a query as well - so make sure to have `'q': '*:*'` as well. The query runs over the documents returned by the query, so if no documents gets returned, the count will also be 0.

Comment: @MatsLindh thank you yes, this is awesome!! Could you please post it as an answer? Thank you for being so helpful. I wouldnt have solved this in decades!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use faceting to get counts for each of the fields you want to, without having to make separate queries for each case.

By using `facet.query` you can run a single query across the documents returned from your main query (`q`). You can give multiple `facet.query` parameters, effectively creating counts for how many documents miss each of the fields (and if you want to filter the document set first, give a query in `q` - for example "how many of the documents with `abc` in the field `tag` is missing name").

```
?q=*:*&facet=true&facet.query=name:[* TO *]&facet.query=address:[* TO *]
```